# simple async android client with simple c# server

Tags: c#, android

I've implemented a very basic client(android,extending asyncTask) and server(C#).Its my first time with android(java) network programming but I've already implemented number of client/server applications in C#/C++ including live video streaming(C#).
Problem : Everything went fine but my android client is receiving every time the same data.
that is "[B@43b9f600".Following is my code for client and server.

```
package com.example.tcpasyncclientbullshittest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String SERVER_IP="192.168.1.3";
    Integer SERVER_PORT = 7878;

    Button connect,start,send;
    EditText smsg,rmsg;

    Socket socket;

    InputStream in;
    OutputStream out;

    byte[] buffer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        send  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

        smsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsg);
        rmsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rmsg);

        buffer = new byte[100];

        socket = new Socket();

        connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
                try {
                    socket.connect(socketAddress);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        class MyParallelReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true){
                    try {
                        in = socket.getInputStream();
                        int bytesReceived = in.read(buffer);
                        if(bytesReceived > 0){
                            publishProgress("He");
                            String data = null;
                            data = buffer.toString();
                            publishProgress(data);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                if(values[0] == "He"){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recvd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    rmsg.append(values[0].toString()+";");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new MyParallelReceiver().execute(new Void[1]);              
            }
        });


        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String sdata = null;
                sdata = smsg.getText().toString();
                if(sdata != null){
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        out = socket.getOutputStream();
                        out.write(sdata.getBytes());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }               
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And c# server :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AndroidTCP_TryTest
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
          const int SERVER_PORT = 7878;
          Socket server;
          Socket client;
          byte[] buffer;
          IPEndPoint client_address;
          Thread receiver;

          public Form1()
          {
               InitializeComponent();
               server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
               receiver = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receive));
          }

          private void Receive() 
          {
               while (true)
               {
                    try
                    {
                         buffer = new byte[100];
                         int nobs = client.Receive(buffer);
                         if (nobs>0)
                         {
                              lock (richTextBoxReceived)
                              {
                                   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { richTextBoxReceived.AppendText("\n" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)); });
                              }                              
                         }
                    }                                                                 
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }                    
               }
          }

          private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               try
               {
                    server.Bind((EndPoint) new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,SERVER_PORT));
                    server.Listen(2);
                    client = server.Accept();
                    richTextBoxReceived.AppendText("\nClient Conected : " + (client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address + " | " + (client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Port + " | " + (client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).AddressFamily);
                    receiver.Start();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }
          }

          private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               if (client.Connected && textBoxSend.Text != String.Empty)
               {
                    buffer = new byte[100];
                    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBoxSend.Text);
                    try
                    {
                         client.Send(buffer);
                         this.Invoke((Action)delegate() { richTextBoxReceived.AppendText("\nSent : " + textBoxSend.Text); });
                         textBoxSend.Clear();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }                    
               }
          }
     }
}
```

i'm frustrated with the problem i need little help and i thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a sanity check why not try modifying your streams to send and receive strings so we can remove all the byte conversion stuff. Just to try and narrow the problem down. Just use a streamreader in C# and printwriter on Android.

Comment: I just changed and used BufferedReader but another problem came out that is when i close my server application the client reads all the sent data by server correctly.But can't understand y?

Comment: at last got the problem and Solved. After using " BufferedReader's readLine() ".The function readLine expects a new line character "\n" in the receiving string and then releases the control.Thast was the problem. :) Thank god. And thank you for the help samuraijourney.

Comment: No problem! Sorry about the late response, I didn't notice the first comment. Glad you got it working though :)